# Switching a @State property to a @Binding property interferes with animation

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am currently building a bottom sheet UI like Apple Map's and I encountered myself with some weird bug that I am struggling to fix.

The following snippet represents the bottom sheet and includes a ready-to-go preview.  You can try it out and see that everything works as expected in both the simulator and in XCode's preview engine.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ReleaseGesture<Header: View, Content: View>: View {
    
    // MARK: Init properties
        
    // Height of the provided header view
    let headerHeight: CGFloat
    
    // Height of the provided content view
    let contentHeight: CGFloat
    
    // The spacing between the header and the content
    let separation: CGFloat
    
    let header: () -> Header
    let content: () -> Content
    
    
    // MARK: State
    @State private var opened = false
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    
    // MARK: Constants
    let capsuleHeight: CGFloat = 5
    let capsulePadding: CGFloat = 5
    
    
    // MARK: Computed properties
    
    // The current static value that is always taken into account to compute the sheet's position
    private var offset: CGFloat {
        self.opened ? self.headerHeight + self.contentHeight : self.headerHeight
    }
    
    // Gesture used for the snap animation
    private var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating(self.$translation) { value, state, transaction in
                state = -value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded {_ in
                self.opened.toggle()
            }
    }
    
    // Animation used when the drag stops
    private var animation: Animation {
        .spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.75, blendDuration: 1.5)
    }


    // Drag indicator used to indicate the user can drag the sheet
    private var dragIndicator: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
            .frame(width: 40, height: capsuleHeight)
            .padding(.vertical, self.capsulePadding)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { reader in
            
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    self.dragIndicator
                    VStack(content: header)
                        .padding(.bottom, self.separation)
                    VStack(content: content)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
                
            }
            // Frame is three times the height to avoid showing the bottom part of the sheet if the user scrolls a lot when the total height turns out to be the maximum height of the screen and is also opened.
            .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.size.height * 3, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.8))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .offset(y: reader.size.height - max(self.translation + self.offset, 0))
            .animation(self.animation, value: self.offset)
            .gesture(self.gesture)
            
        }
        .clipped()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Initializer
    init(
        headerHeight: CGFloat,
        contentHeight: CGFloat,
        separation: CGFloat,
        @ViewBuilder header: @escaping () -> Header,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.headerHeight = headerHeight + self.capsuleHeight + self.capsulePadding * 2 + separation
        self.contentHeight = contentHeight
        self.separation = separation
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
}

struct ReleaseGesture_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    struct WrapperView: View {
        
        @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        
        @State private var opened = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                ReleaseGesture(
                    headerHeight: 25,
                    contentHeight: 300,
                    separation: 30,
                    header: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                            .frame(height: 30)
                    },
                    content: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.orange.opacity(0.2))
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        
                    }
                )
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        WrapperView()
    }
}
```

Now we switch the `opened` property to be a `Binding` property so that the parent view can know the state of the bottom sheet.

Here is the code with the changes.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ReleaseGesture<Header: View, Content: View>: View {
    
    // MARK: Init properties
    
    // Binding property that shares the state of the sheet to the parent view
    @Binding private var opened: Bool
    
    // Height of the provided header view
    let headerHeight: CGFloat
    
    // Height of the provided content view
    let contentHeight: CGFloat
    
    // The spacing between the header and the content
    let separation: CGFloat
    
    let header: () -> Header
    let content: () -> Content
    
    
    // MARK: State
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    
    // MARK: Constants
    let capsuleHeight: CGFloat = 5
    let capsulePadding: CGFloat = 5
    
    
    // MARK: Computed properties
    
    // The current static value that is always taken into account to compute the sheet's position
    private var offset: CGFloat {
        self.opened ? self.headerHeight + self.contentHeight : self.headerHeight
    }
    
    // Gesture used for the snap animation
    private var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating(self.$translation) { value, state, transaction in
                state = -value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded {_ in
                self.opened.toggle()
            }
    }
    
    // Animation used when the drag stops
    private var animation: Animation {
        .spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.75, blendDuration: 1.5)
    }


    // Drag indicator used to indicate the user can drag the sheet
    private var dragIndicator: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
            .frame(width: 40, height: capsuleHeight)
            .padding(.vertical, self.capsulePadding)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { reader in
            
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    self.dragIndicator
                    VStack(content: header)
                        .padding(.bottom, self.separation)
                    VStack(content: content)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
                
            }
            // Frame is three times the height to avoid showing the bottom part of the sheet if the user scrolls a lot when the total height turns out to be the maximum height of the screen and is also opened.
            .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.size.height * 3, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.8))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .offset(y: reader.size.height - max(self.translation + self.offset, 0))
            .animation(self.animation, value: self.offset)
            .gesture(self.gesture)
            
        }
        .clipped()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Initializer
    init(
        opened: Binding<Bool>,
        headerHeight: CGFloat,
        contentHeight: CGFloat,
        separation: CGFloat,
        @ViewBuilder header: @escaping () -> Header,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self._opened = opened
        self.headerHeight = headerHeight + self.capsuleHeight + self.capsulePadding * 2 + separation
        self.contentHeight = contentHeight
        self.separation = separation
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
}

struct ReleaseGesture_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    struct WrapperView: View {
        
        @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        
        @State private var opened = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                ReleaseGesture(
                    opened: self.$opened,
                    headerHeight: 25,
                    contentHeight: 300,
                    separation: 30,
                    header: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                            .frame(height: 30)
                    },
                    content: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.orange.opacity(0.2))
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        
                    }
                )
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        WrapperView()
    }
}

}
```

However, if you run the preview in XCode you'll see that when the drag gesture stops, instead of the sheet snapping back to the "opened" state from where we lift the finger off, it does the animation from its initial position.

Weirdly enough, if you try to run this in an iPhone or in the simulator, it behaves as expected, as in the first example. **Although I've tried to use the code in a more "complex" app (it has a TabView and some few more things) and the same bug appears**.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is an example with the example view used in a real app tested in a real iPhone. You'll see that the bug is very noticeable.

**Video:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvrmz.jpg

Comment: Preview has limited run-time functionality comparing to Simulator (actually Preview is only preview - main goal is previewing static screens), so if it works on real device (and even on Simulator) - just ignore bug in Preview.

Comment: @Asperi that's what I'd like to do, but when I use that very same code in another app that is a bit more complex (the only thing different is that it is an app with a TabView), the problem also happens in real devices.

Comment: @Asperi I have added a video to the original post so you can see the bug in an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I see here some misunderstanding that must be clarified and, probably, then initial solution should be rethink. Binding is not *state shared to parent*, it is link to parent's state holding source of truth, so your view becomes dependent on parent's capability to refresh it on state change, which is not always reliable (or stable, or persistent, etc.), especially in different view hierarchies (like, sheets, UIKit backend, etc.). Changing binding you do not refresh your view directly (as opposite to changes own state) even if your view depends on value in binding, but change parent state, which might do or might do not update your view back. Finalizing - what you've implied is not reliable approach by nature, and you actually observe this.

*Alternate solution:* use `ObsevableObject/ObservedObject` view model pattern.

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
import MapKit

class ReleaseGestureVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var opened: Bool = false
}

struct ReleaseGesture<Header: View, Content: View>: View {

    // MARK: Init properties
    @ObservedObject var vm: ReleaseGestureVM

    // Height of the provided header view
    let headerHeight: CGFloat

    // Height of the provided content view
    let contentHeight: CGFloat

    // The spacing between the header and the content
    let separation: CGFloat

    let header: () -> Header
    let content: () -> Content


    // MARK: State
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0


    // MARK: Constants
    let capsuleHeight: CGFloat = 5
    let capsulePadding: CGFloat = 5


    // MARK: Computed properties

    // The current static value that is always taken into account to compute the sheet's position
    private var offset: CGFloat {
        self.vm.opened ? self.headerHeight + self.contentHeight : self.headerHeight
    }

    // Gesture used for the snap animation
    private var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating(self.$translation) { value, state, transaction in
                state = -value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded {_ in
                self.vm.opened.toggle()
            }
    }

    // Animation used when the drag stops
    private var animation: Animation {
        .spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.75, blendDuration: 1.5)
    }


    // Drag indicator used to indicate the user can drag the sheet
    private var dragIndicator: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
            .frame(width: 40, height: capsuleHeight)
            .padding(.vertical, self.capsulePadding)
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { reader in


            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    self.dragIndicator
                    VStack(content: header)
                        .padding(.bottom, self.separation)
                    VStack(content: content)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)


            }
            // Frame is three times the height to avoid showing the bottom part of the sheet if the user scrolls a lot when the total height turns out to be the maximum height of the screen and is also opened.
            .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.size.height * 3, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.8))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .offset(y: reader.size.height - max(self.translation + self.offset, 0))
            .animation(self.animation, value: self.offset)
            .gesture(self.gesture)

        }
        .clipped()
    }


    // MARK: Initializer
    init(
        vm: ReleaseGestureVM,
        headerHeight: CGFloat,
        contentHeight: CGFloat,
        separation: CGFloat,
        @ViewBuilder header: @escaping () -> Header,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.vm = vm
        self.headerHeight = headerHeight + self.capsuleHeight + self.capsulePadding * 2 + separation
        self.contentHeight = contentHeight
        self.separation = separation
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
}

struct ReleaseGesture_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    struct WrapperView: View {

        @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))

        @StateObject private var vm = ReleaseGestureVM()

        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                ReleaseGesture(
                    vm: self.vm,
                    headerHeight: 25,
                    contentHeight: 300,
                    separation: 30,
                    header: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                            .frame(height: 30)
                    },
                    content: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.orange.opacity(0.2))
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

                    }
                )
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()

        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        WrapperView()
    }
}
```